# two brownian motions in $ \mathbb{Z}^2 $

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

I was wondering what is the probability for 2 brownian walkers coming from 2 different initial positions to be at the same position at time t.

I consider that at each step, each point can independently move of $(0,\pm1)$ or $(\pm1, 0)$ with probability $\frac14$ for each direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the difference between the two starting positions is $(x,y)$, then the two particles are at the same position at time $n$ with probability
$$
\frac1{4^{n+1}\pi^2}\iint_{[-\pi,\pi]^2}\left(\cos u+\cos v\right)^{2n}\,\cos(ux+vy)\,\mathrm du\mathrm dv.
$$
To see this, note that a random variable $(X,Y)$ with values in $\mathbb Z^2$ equals $(0,0)$ with probability
$$
\frac1{4\pi^2}\iint_{[-\pi,\pi]^2}E\left(\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(uX+vY)}\right)\,\mathrm du\mathrm dv.
$$
Of course, whether the formula given in this post is explicit or not is at best debatable...

Comment: I get that... $\frac{1}{2}(\cos u + \cos v) = \frac{1}{4}(e^{iu}+ e^{iv} + e^{-iu} + e^{-iv})$ like a [transfer operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_operator).  So you are taking the $(0,0)$ Fourier coefficient of  $$\frac{1}{4}(e^{iu}+ e^{iv} + e^{-iu} + e^{-iv})$$

Comment: @did : Ok, thanks for your answer, it is clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

Brownian motion on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is just a random walk.  The motion in the $x$ and $y$ directions are independent walks.

In the **x direction** walk with  probability $\frac{1}{4}$ of moving left-right, $\frac{1}{2}$ of staying in place.

You can draw something like [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) in this case.  In fact, just the even rows.

```
    1
  1 2 1 
1 4 6 4 1
```

Every time we step, we are asking if the coin is heads or tails.

$$ X_i = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \mathbb{P}(H) = \frac{1}{2}\\
0 & \mathbb{P}(T) = \frac{1}{2}\end{array} \right.$$

The random walk in the *x* axis is $Y = \sum_{i=0}^N X_i$.

For two random walkers to be in the same place, their difference must be zero.  However, as a probability distribution $Y = - Y$.

$$ \mathbb{P}(Y_1 - Y_2 = 0) =  \mathbb{P}(Y_1 + Y_2 = 0) 
=    \mathbb{P}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{2N} = 0\right) = \binom{2n}{n}$$

For since both axes are independent, we take the square of this number $ \frac{1}{16^n}\binom{2n}{n}^2$

Comment: It's strange ...
first I don't think that movement in the x or y direction is independent.
Secondly I don't understand how it is possible that the result doesn't depend on initial positions. In fact, if the two walkers start on (0,0) and (0,2), there is a probability 1/16 that they meet at t=1 in (0,1), whereas if they start on (0,0) and (1000,1000) it's unlikely that they meet each other.
And finally if they start on (0,0) and (0,1), they just can't meet each other for all t.

Comment: Yes it is strange.  However, for random walks in the plane the **x** and **y** directions are independent.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk2-Dimensional.html You can still use Pascal's triangle to find out when $\mathbb{P}(Y_1 - Y_2) = 0$.  Instead it is $\binom{2n}{n-2}$

Comment: Sorry, but i was thinking about a walk on a 2D-lattice. And for example, if you came from $(0,0)$ and that $x=1$ at $t=1$, you are sure that $y=0$ so $x$ and $y$ aren't independent, I think...

Comment: I don't know then.  What if your steps were $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ instead of $(\pm 1,0), (0,\pm 1)$ ?  Why don't you edit the question and write a clearer definition of 2D random walk?  It should be clear enough that we can decide if moving in the **x** and **y** directions are independent.

Comment: The definition is already in the post and states unambiguously that the motions in the x and y direction are not independent.